# @angular/cli build exclude assets subdirectory for --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have test data located under `assets/test/` that I don't want to be included in a production deployment.

How do I configure `@angular/cli` to ignore / exclude that folder when running `ng build --prod`?
Adding an `exclude` section to the `tsconfig.json` as suggested elsewhere did not result in any observable change (i.e. the files where still under `dist/assets/test` after `ng build --prod` was run).

```
"compilerOptions": { ... },
"exclude" : [ "src/assets/test" ]
```

Is tere another way to properly exclude certain files or folders from the `ng build` process?

Comment: the purpose of the asset folder is to not be touched by the cli can't you move this file somewhere else?

Comment: Create an other folder /app/test and move your files and change relative paths in your code. It is sure to work :)

Comment: @EduardoVargas @Vega I was keeping the files under `assets` to easily be able to retrieve them via `http.get()`. This does not seem possible with angular-cli when the files do not reside under `assets`, is it?

Comment: @TommyF did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @IbeVanmeenen not directly, we removed the files later in the build process since we couldn't find a clean solution for this through angular.

Comment: @TommyF Ok, thanks for the respons! 

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe a little too late, anyway you can get the behaviour you desire by specifiyng the assets content as a glob in your `angular.json` file:

```
"projects": {
    "myapp": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets", "ignore": ["**/test/*"], "output": "/assets" }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've since switched to VueJS so I can't confirm if that works but I'll mark your answer as the solution for now and hope it helps others.

Comment: Thx for the hint! I had to put "[\**/test/**/\*]" into "ignore" to make it work

Comment: Here you can find more detailed documentation: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Comment: Thank you for this, I spent forever twiddling with my tsconfigs to no avail. This is exactly what I needed.